# Sorting list of records on a specific type

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have a list of Games :

```
data Game = Game {
                    round ::Int
                  , time :: Maybe ZonedTime
                  , location :: String 
                  , hometeam :: String 
                  , awayteam :: String 
                  , result :: Maybe (Int, Int) 
                  } deriving (Show)

type Games = [Game]
```

How do I sort the Games list  based on the time property ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sortOn` from Data.List:

```
sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Conveniently enough, `Maybe a` is an instance of `Ord`, when `a` is itself an instance of `Ord`, so you can sort the `ZonedTime` values "through" the maybes:

```
sortOn time games -- produces the list you're looking for
```

The `Ord` instance of `Maybe` also takes care of the `Nothing` values by giving them a lower ordering:

```
$> sort [Just 5, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing]
$> [Nothing,Nothing,Just 1,Just 5]
```

This is assuming `ZonedTime` is an instance of `Ord`. If it's not, and it's in your control, then you can make it one, but I think that should be addressed in another Q&A if need be.